# If cell A1 contains the string 'john' then cell B1 should return 'red', if cell A2 contains the string 'paul' then cell V2 should return 'blue'

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say we have a table like below which pairs each name with a colour:

| Name | Colour |
| --- | --- |
| Paul | blue |
| John | red |

I'm  looking to create a formula in the 2nd column below that will return the colour associated with the name if the 1st column contains the name anywhere in the string.

| Data | Colour |
| --- | --- |
| Paul*6871628 | blue |
| paul*6871628 | blue |
| apda23.zzJohn | red |
| asdazjohn | red |
| borp paul reck | blue |
| jgk John wqty | red |

Comment: This is doable in Google Sheets, and probably also in Microsoft Excel, but it is likely that no single solution can cover both platforms. If your question is regarding Google Sheets, please delete the `microsoft-excel` tag.

Comment: I removed the excel tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `search()` and `filter()`, like this:

```
=lambda( 
  searchKeys, names, colors, 
  map( 
    searchKeys, 
    lambda( 
      searchKey, 
      iferror( single( filter(colors, search(names, searchKey)) ) ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)(A2:A, Names!A2:A, Names!B2:B)
```

The formula is a bit on the heavy side, so you may want to remove any unneeded blank rows at the bottom of the data and search tabs.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much. Really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm curious to know why you went for this approach when if we use the formula below which is at the core of your solution we seem to get the same result? "=iferror( single( filter(colors, search(names, searchKey)) ) ) :

Comment: The formula you quote needs to be copied down. You can make it work like this: `=iferror( single( filter(Names!B$2:B, search(Names!A$2:A, A2)) ) )`. The formula in the answer is an array formula that fills the whole column automatically, which makes spreadsheet management easier by avoiding one-off typos and the like.

Comment: thanks so much! this is super helpful.